# How to specify file output directory when run user's code?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a api server, to run user's code.
And if the code have some write file action. Have any way to specify file output directory?
I want to create an uuid directory for every requests,and save their's  files.Then response the file.

I have some idea, egs,
1. Run requests with docker by -v (I think it's slow)
2. Add code head, like

```py
import os
os.chdir(...)
```

Have any good way to complete this api?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Axuim Sorry, I don't understand. The user's code will like this: `with open("./good.txt", "w") as fp: ...`, I want to make the `good.txt ` create in a `./uuid/filename`

Comment: then make it an absolute path.

Comment: @Axium But user's code is what, I don't know. I find a way, the OJ can do this.

Comment: OJ? also just use `os.path.join()` with `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Online Judge. emm, for every user request's python file. I will run `python -I xxx.py`. Did mean change user code? Like add code head?